# oralce apex_json to extract fields

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Oracle 11g with Apex 5 is installed in my system. And I'm looking for the basic extraction of the field1 : total from the below json.

```
DECLARE 
    j apex_json.t_values; 
BEGIN 
    apex_json.parse(j, '{"total":83,"netAmmount":65}'); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Total   : ' ||
    APEX_JSON.get_number( 'total'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('netAmmount: ' ||
    APEX_JSON.get_number( 'netAmmount'));
END;
```

Could you please let me know how to extract field1 and 2 using only oracle apex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the `JSON` value has no array, therefore no need to use `apex_json.t_values` which can be replaced with a local variable of type `varchar2` :

```
DECLARE 
    j    varchar2(32767) := '{"total":83,"netAmmount":65}'; 
BEGIN 
    APEX_JSON.parse( j ); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Total      : '||APEX_JSON.get_number( path => 'total' ) );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Net Amount : '||APEX_JSON.get_number( path => 'netAmmount' ) );
END;
/
```

If the value of a field is a string, then replace `APEX_JSON.get_number` with `APEX_JSON.get_varchar2` for that.

Comment: thanks Mr.Özhan . but for some reason with `path=>` didn't work. I removed and tried and it worked. Can you tell me how to update those values in the existing json. If there is a json `{"total":23,"netAmmount":45,"quantity":12}` , how do I update those results into the existing json?

Comment: you're welcome @user1720827 . You can use `APEX_JSON.open_object` and `APEX_JSON.write` methods after splitting.